# CSS - better way to remove class in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have a menu of 5 items. When I click any item, I add a class to change color on it. I also remove the color from the other 4 items, whether they have color or not. Is there a better way, perhaps through CSS, to remove those classes that aren't selected?

```
 switch(currentC.data("template")) {
  case "cataction1": {
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction1Current" );
    $( ".catbarlist li" ).not( currentC ).removeClass( "cataction2Current cataction3Current cataction4Current cataction5Current active activenotransit" ); 
    break;
  }
  case "cataction2": {
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction2Current" );
    $( ".catbarlist li" ).not( currentC ).removeClass( "cataction1Current cataction3Current cataction4Current cataction5Current active activenotransit" ); 
    break;
  }
  case "cataction3": {
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction3Current" );
    $( ".catbarlist li" ).not( currentC ).removeClass( "cataction1Current cataction2Current cataction4Current cataction5Current active activenotransit" ); 
    break;
  }
  case "cataction4": {
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction4Current" );
    $( ".catbarlist li" ).not( currentC ).removeClass( "cataction1Current cataction2Current cataction3Current cataction5Current active activenotransit" ); 
    break;
  }
  case "cataction5": {
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction5Current" );
    $( ".catbarlist li" ).not( currentC ).removeClass( "cataction1Current cataction2Current cataction3Current cataction4Current active activenotransit" ); 
    break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: I agree: a working example would be helpful. Why does each element need it's own unique "current" class?

Comment: So much copy and pasting in that code. What is the CSS?

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle. It's very difficult to understand the structure of your HTML from this.

Answer (score 1):

Drop using a unique class for each item and use a single common class for marking current item.

For example, with jQuery:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my-menu > LI', function() {
    // Unmarking previously marked item.
    $(this.parentNode).children('.cur').removeClass('cur');

    // Marking new current item.
    $(this).addClass('cur');
});
```

Comment: He already has an `active` class. Apparently he needs the other classes, too. Not sure why.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Looks like a bad practice (maybe some legacy code originally intended for e.g. IE6 not capable of combining classes in selectors), so I've recommended a better practice.

Comment: That's pure speculation. Without seeing the HTML and CSS we can only assume there's a good reason for all those classes (although, to be honest, I cannot fathom what it could be).

Answer (score 0):

I assume all those classes are necessary (as you have an `.active` class already). I also assume there's a good reason you're not using a `click` event.

If so, the first thing you could do is make it a lot cleaner/easier on yourself by creating a `function` to remove the unwanted styles. Lots of repeating code is not good -- hard to read, hard to maintain. For example:

```
function removeCatbarColor() {
    $(".catbarlist li").removeClass("cataction1Current cataction2Current 
    cataction3Current cataction4Current cataction5Current active activenotransit");
}
```

And then calling it before applying the style to the active one:

```
switch(currentC.data("template")) {
  case "cataction1": {
    removeCatbarColor();
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction1Current" );
    break;
  }
  case "cataction2": {
    removeCatbarColor();
    currentC.addClass( "active cataction2Current" );
    break;
  }
  ...
```

There could probably be further improvements, but without seeing your HTML/CSS I can only guess. (Do you really need so many classes? A working JSFiddle would really  help.)

---

A better way of handling things, given your description below, would be to have permanent classes for each `cataction`. So something like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="cataction1">Link</li>
  <li class="cataction2">Link</li>
  <li class="cataction3">Link</li>
  <li class="cataction4">Link</li>
</ul>
```

That way all you need in your CSS is:

```
.cataction1 { 
  // styles when not active
}
.cataction1.active {
  // styles when active
}
// etc
```

Which allows you to simplify your JS like so:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

That is a much better way of handling things.

Comment: Hi Chuck LeButt :), Yes - I should put up some code to show better and will do when back at desk. The reason why I have another class after Active is for a color change on the text - besides having active (which adds an underline to the menu item) - each clicked / selected menu item needs its own color.

Answer (score 0):

Example menu:

```
<li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
```

Add the following CSS:

```
 .menu-item .active{
         background-color:#1B3E70;
         color:white;

    }
```

Then with jquery:

```
$('.menu-item a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution might be:

```
$(document).on("click", ".catbarlist li", function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```